# じゃなくて + verb: What are their uses?

Tags: sentence, negation

私のこと大事にしてくれるから優しくしようと引くじゃなくて

うんと話して好きにして欲しい

For what I understand the character is saying that because the other character cares about them, he has drawing back in an attempt to be kind, but the character speaking wants him to talk an do what he wants.

My confusion is about the use of the 優しくしようと引くじゃなくて

What exactly is the じゃなくて doing here?

Comment: Are you sure you are quoting correctly? Anyway,  じゃなくて means *instead of* here.

Comment: 引くじゃなくて looks like a typo to me.

Answer (score 4):

じゃなくて literally means "It's not [Clause]" and idiomatically "instead of" as sundowner commented, because it is followed by an affirmative sentence that tells us what this "it" is referring to, giving us, "It's not A, it's B".

> 優しくしようと引くじゃなくてうんと話して好きにして欲しい 
> It's not your drawing back trying to be kind, I desire your talking a lot and doing what you want -> What I desire is not your drawing back trying to be kind, but your talking a lot and doing what you want.

Another example (LN title):

> 娘じゃなくて私が好きなの！？ 
> It's not my daughter, you like me!? -> The one you like is not my daughter, but me!?